# how to perform jQuery live filter on divs and not list items?

Tags: jquery, html, filter

I think the feature i am looking for is called 'live filter' and i am trying to filter outputted database entries where each entry has the following structure:

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3" data-name="name" data-date="MM/DD/YY">
    <img src="path/to/image.jpg">
    <div class="class4">
        <h4>some text here</h4> <!-- this is what i want to search in -->
        <div class="class5">
            <span id="date">date: MM/DD/YY</span>
            <span id="id_one">text</span>
        </div>
        <div class="class6">
            <span id="id_two">text</span>
            <span id="id_three">text</span>
        </div>
        <span id="id_four">text</span>
        <span id="id_five"><a class= class7 href="path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am wanting to search within .class4 h4 and then fade out all `.class1` divs that do not contain the searched for text.

This is the default behaviour of the solutions I have come across (mainly [here](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/5-jquery-live-filter-plugins/)) however they seem to only function with list items and not divs.  for example, i tried the code from [here](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/) and modified it to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#filter").keyup(function() {
            // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
            var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;

            // Loop through the comment list
            $(".class4 h4").each(function() {
                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(".class1").fadeOut();
                    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } 
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                }
            });

            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("# of matches = "+count);
        });
    });
</script>
```

and it searched correctly but it hid all the divs with `.class1`.

does anyone know how a live filter could be used to search `.class4 h4` for specific text and then fade out div's with `.class1` that do not contain the text searched for?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

use onkeypress

ex:

```
 <input type="text" onkeypress=" return callfunction(event); "
```

In the callfunction you can then implement the fade out logic.

call function should look like this:

```
function callfunction(event){   
// Loop through the comment list
            $(".class4 h4").each(function() {
                // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                    $(".class1").fadeOut();
                    // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                } 
                else {
                    $(this).show();
                    count++;
                }
            });

            // Update the count
            var numberItems = count;
            $("#filter-count").text("# of matches = "+count);}          
}
```

And there is not need for the function to be in the document ready method

Comment: thank you for your reply, i added the code above to my input line and the required functionality did not work. thank you.

Comment: it reaches the function on every call no? put an alert in the new version of the callfunction and check if it enters every time you type. If it alerts everty time, then it's ok and your logic it not good.

Comment: hello, i tried the code exactly as above and it didn't function, thank you.

Comment: hy, I'll make you a live demo in 4-5 hours, if I forget please remind me because I am very busy. I promise you it will work :)

Answer (score 1):

As I told you, I got back with the live demo. Here is the code:

> ***Just make sure you include the jquery script.

```
<label>Type here</label>

<input type="text" id="filter" onkeyup=" return callfunction(); " />

<div>
    <div class="class1 class2 class3" data-name="name" data-date="MM/DD/YY">
        <img  src="@Url.Content("~/StaticContent/Images/cycling_logo.gif")" width="90" height="90">
        <div class="class4">
            <h4>abcdef</h4> <!-- this is what i want to search in -->
            <div class="class5">
                <span id="date">date: MM/DD/YY</span>
                <span id="id_one">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="class6">
                <span id="id_two">text</span>
                <span id="id_three">text</span>
            </div>
            <span id="id_four">text</span>
            <span id="id_five"><a class= class7 href="path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="class1 class2 class3" data-name="name" data-date="MM/DD/YY">
        <img  src="@Url.Content("~/StaticContent/Images/cycling_logo.gif")" width="90" height="90">
        <div class="class4">
            <h4>some</h4> <!-- this is what i want to search in -->
            <div class="class5">
                <span id="date">date: MM/DD/YY</span>
                <span id="id_one">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="class6">
                <span id="id_two">text</span>
                <span id="id_three">text</span>
            </div>
            <span id="id_four">text</span>
            <span id="id_five"><a class= class7 href="path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="class1 class2 class3" data-name="name" data-date="MM/DD/YY">
        <img  src="@Url.Content("~/StaticContent/Images/cycling_logo.gif")" width="90" height="90">
        <div class="class4">
            <h4>dcdef</h4> <!-- this is what i want to search in -->
            <div class="class5">
                <span id="date">date: MM/DD/YY</span>
                <span id="id_one">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="class6">
                <span id="id_two">text</span>
                <span id="id_three">text</span>
            </div>
            <span id="id_four">text</span>
            <span id="id_five"><a class= class7 href="path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="class1 class2 class3" data-name="name" data-date="MM/DD/YY">
        <img  src="@Url.Content("~/StaticContent/Images/cycling_logo.gif")" width="90" height="90">
        <div class="class4">
            <h4>dcfffff</h4> <!-- this is what i want to search in -->
            <div class="class5">
                <span id="date">date: MM/DD/YY</span>
                <span id="id_one">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="class6">
                <span id="id_two">text</span>
                <span id="id_three">text</span>
            </div>
            <span id="id_four">text</span>
            <span id="id_five"><a class= class7 href="path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="class1 class2 class3" data-name="name" data-date="MM/DD/YY">
        <img  src="@Url.Content("~/StaticContent/Images/cycling_logo.gif")" width="90" height="90">
        <div class="class4">
            <h4>dssfafafsa</h4> <!-- this is what i want to search in -->
            <div class="class5">
                <span id="date">date: MM/DD/YY</span>
                <span id="id_one">text</span>
            </div>
            <div class="class6">
                <span id="id_two">text</span>
                <span id="id_three">text</span>
            </div>
            <span id="id_four">text</span>
            <span id="id_five"><a class= class7 href="path/to/link.html">link</a></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/latest/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function callfunction() {
        $(".class4 h4").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf($("#filter").val()) != 0) {
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeOut(500);
            } else {
                $(this).parent().parent().fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: thank you very much, i will be able to test this in about 8 hours and will respond, thank you for your time.

Comment: hello, i have created jsfiddle based on the above and it doesn't seem to be functioning. http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/SuEQC/. thank you.

Comment: jsfiddle has a problem: http://jsfiddle.net/slown1/SuEQC/4/ solved :) replace the  first line with this: " window.callfunction = function() {//the code from the function

Comment: thank you. on my live test site it is fading out more than the divs required, is there anyway to target only divs with .class1? just for clarity, as i'm signing off for the day, as in op 'I am wanting to search within .class4 h4 and then fade out all .class1 divs that do not contain the searched for text'.  thank you.

Comment: ps, the following causes all divs with class1 to fade out regardless of whether they contain the searched for text or not: `    function callfunction() {
        $(".class4 h4").each(function() {
            if ($(this).text().indexOf($("#filter").val()) != 0) {
                $(".class1").fadeOut(500);
            } else {
                $(".class1").fadeIn(500);
            }
        });
    }`

Comment: I'll respond to you tomorrow because I am very bussy now.

Comment: hello, if anyone is able to assist with this last part it would be much appreciated. thank you.

Comment: Hy, sry because I forgot, In 6-7 hours I'll be free and I will help.